# "no matching function call to 'bind'" when compiling using the Android NDK

Tags: c++, templates, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to port one of my OpenGL applications to Android using the NDK, and I'm hitting a weird compilation error that I just can't figure out!

I have the following template functions to help detect OpenGL errors:

```
template<typename Res, typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker {
    static Res run(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
        Res result = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
        check_and_log_error("", 0);
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker<void, Func, Args...> {
    static void run(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
        std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
        check_and_log_error("", 0);
    }
};

template<typename Func>
struct Checker<void, Func> {
    static void run(Func&& func) {
        func();
        check_and_log_error("", 0);
    }
};

}

template<typename Res=void, typename Func, typename... Args>
Res GLCheck(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    GLThreadCheck::check();
    return GLChecker::Checker<Res, Func, Args...>::run(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I can then call OpenGL functions like this:

```
GLCheck(glBindTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_tex_);
```

And the application will log an error if that call failed for some reason. This all works fine on the desktop, but when I try to compile for Android, every single OpenGL call gives compilation errors like this:

```
kglt/kglt/utils/gl_error.h:30:9: error: no matching function for call to 'bind'
        std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
        ^~~~~~~~~
kglt/kglt/utils/gl_error.h:48:52: note: in instantiation of member function 'GLChecker::Checker<void, void (&)(unsigned int, unsigned int) __attribute__((pcs("aapcs"))), int, unsigned int &>::run' requested here
    return GLChecker::Checker<Res, Func, Args...>::run(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                                                   ^
kglt/kglt/texture.cpp:77:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'GLCheck<void, void (&)(unsigned int, unsigned int) __attribute__((pcs("aapcs"))), int, unsigned int &>' requested here
    GLCheck(glBindTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_tex_);
    ^
/home/kazade/Android/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/functional:1682:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Result'
    bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
    ^
/home/kazade/Android/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/functional:1655:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Func = void (&)(unsigned int, unsigned int) __attribute__((pcs("aapcs"))),
      _BoundArgs = <int, unsigned int &>]
    bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
```

I can't understand why the template deduction is failing, especially as the "subsitution failure" above seems to show compatible arguments being passed down. The only strange thing that I can see is the `__attribute__((pcs("aapcs")))` that is part of the OpenGL function.

Can anyone see where the problem is?

*EDIT: Just saw that the call to bind is entirely pointless, I can call the passed function directly. Even still, I'm curious to know what was causing it to fail anyway :)*

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the code you provided with clang-3.5 and g++ 4.8.2 no erorrs.

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

#include <GL/gl.h>

namespace GLChecker {
template <typename Res, typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker {
  static Res run(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    Res result
        = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
    // check_and_log_error("", 0);
    return result;
  }
};

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
struct Checker<void, Func, Args...> {
  static void run(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
    // check_and_log_error("", 0);
  }
};

template <typename Func>
struct Checker<void, Func> {
  static void run(Func&& func) {
    func();
    // check_and_log_error("", 0);
  }
};
}

template <typename Res = void, typename Func, typename... Args>
Res GLCheck(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
  // GLThreadCheck::check();
  return GLChecker::Checker<Res, Func, Args...>::run(
      std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  int gl_tex_ = 0;
  GLCheck(glBindTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_tex_);

  return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11  ~/Desktop/main.cpp -lGL
```

or

```
clang++ -std=c++11  ~/Desktop/main.cpp -lGL
```

Comment: Definitely something to do with Android then, although the Android NDK only has clang 3.3 so it might be that...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's caused by the c++ standard version, when compile you can try adding -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ to the compiler arguments

Comment: Yeah, tried that :( I got it working though by removing the bind() call, wish I knew why though.